# Changing a Pre-Populated Sqlite-Database in React Native

Tags: react-native, sqlite

I am using a Sqlite-Database in my React Native Application.

When I make changes to the Database I want to update the Database in my App as well. So I copy the updated db file into the default www folders. Then on startup of the app I want to delete the existing (old) db file using:

`SQLite.deleteDatabase({name: 'ChemoDatabase.db', location: 1},() => {console.log('db deleted');     }, error => {console.log('ERROR: ' + error);})`

And reopen the updated db file inside the app with:

`SQLite.openDatabase({name: 'ChemoDatabase.db', createFromLocation: 1});`

However after that the app still uses the outdated Database which should be deleted with SQLite.deleteDatabase().

The only way that I got the app to use the updated db file is by rebuilding the whole app...

I tried to update my db file, delete the db file on the device and reopen it - however it still uses the old db data.